# Oracle Apex 5 - IG toolbar flashing

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

I am using Oracle Apex 5.1.3

When I scroll down over my IG , I see IG toolbar flashing something.

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**I solve it by set Heading ---> Fixed To ---> None**